# Overflow in spanned row with one row collapsed

Tags: css, html-table, webkit, overflow

I'd like to have overflow working inside row that is spanned and another being collapsed.

Right now the text is clipped, but when the row is uncollapsed - overflow works.
I tried `position: absolute` and it works...until you start scrolling. If I start putting `position: relative` anywhere the text becomes clipped again.

I searched for any hints but I found that this is how Webkit implemented it apparently: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/478#issuecomment-318539983
There is no problem on Firefox, only on Webkit browsers.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
  positon: relative;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.collapsed {
  visibility: collapse;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

/* span {
  position: absolute;
} */
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2"><span>Very long sentence</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2 collapsed"><td>2</td></tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Very long sentence</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#change").click(function(){
    
    $(".row2").toggleClass("collapsed");
    
    // $(".spannedtd").removeAttr("rowspan");
    
    $('.spannedtd').attr('rowspan', function(index, attr){
      
        return attr == '2' ? null : '2';
      
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
table {
  
  border-collapse: collapse;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

/* tr{

  height: 20px;
  
  position: relative;
  
} */

td{
  
  max-width: 100px;
  
/*   height: 20px; */
  
  vertical-align: top;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

.collapsed {
  
  visibility: collapse;
  
}

div{
  
  height: 300px;
  
  overflow: scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="change" class="btn btn-primary">Change Visibility</button>

<br/>

<br/>

<div>

  <table>

    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>

 <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>
      
      <tr>

        <td>1</td>

        <td rowspan="2" class="spannedtd"><span>Data Data Data Data</span></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class="row2">

        <td>2</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Above code [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/shads06/pen/VwLKzwr)

I have removed the rowspan on button click.

**NOTE**: *Click on the change button above scroll window to see the change in table after applying **visibility: collapse***

[image: Screenshot of code output showing change button user has to click to see changes]

Comment: That doesn't solve anything because you changed the width of the column. The problem is with `overflow` meaning when the content doesn't fit the table cell.

Comment: So you want to see the overflow content in the table cell that is hiding?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve the result from Firefox, when the text is not clipped and I can use overflow + I can scroll the whole table.

Comment: The problem is when you have a row with rowspan that includes a row that is collapsed, it disables `overflow` for a whole row. And it includes the part of the row that is not collapsed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the updated code and updated codepen link. In updated code I'm removing the rowspan and it is working fine. Check the output and tell me if it requires modification or it has solve your problem.

Comment: You're right, it's a workaround, but the result is what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept this answer if it is solving your problem. Thank you :)